# visual studio 2010 doesn't update qrc files

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, qt, qml

I have a project on visual studio 2010 which uses qt, qrc files and qml. I've put my qml files inside qrc file, so when I rebuild the project my qrc files updates and I can reach my qml files.

The problem is when I update my qml files, visual studio (or qt visual studio plugin) can't detect the change and doesn't update the qrc files. Only thing I can do is either rebuild the project, or make some dummy changes to qrc file (add remove some white-space characters) so that qt plugin thinks that there may be some change in qrc file and it updates the qrc file.

This is time consuming, as I make several changes to my qml files it takes too much time to do this manually every time. Is there a practical way to do this?

Comment: I prefer doing Qt Programming in qtcreator, I recommend it. It avoid a lot of configuration overhead.

Comment: that's a nice advice, but unfortunately I don't have a chance to change my ide right now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Right-Click the file and select compile should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's simpler than I think.